# Wordpress - сортировка постов по дате

Tags: php, wordpress

Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать сортировку постов для определенной категории по дате по возрастанию. То есть нужно добиться, чтобы пост опубликованный последним выводился последним, а не первым. Повторюсь, что это нужно сделать только для одной категории. Сейчас используется стандартный цикл вывода постов.

```
<?php if( have_posts() ){ while( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php } /* конец while */ ?>

    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
        <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
    </div>

<?php
} // конец if
else 
    echo "<h2>Записей нет.</h2>";
```

То есть сейчас пост опубликованный последним, отображается первым. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого вам понадобится внести дополнительные параметры в основную выборку постов для данной категории. Это делается с помощью [хуков](https://wp-kama.ru/hooks).

В данном случае [примерно](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#targeting-the-right-query) так:

```
// Регистрируем хук и передаем название функции, 
// которая будет вносить изменения в выборку
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_my_category_by_date' );

// Пишем саму функцию, которая внедрит нужную сортировку
function sort_my_category_by_date( $query ) {

    // Убеждаемся, что изменения не касаются админки
    // и что мы применяем сортировку именно к основной выборке постов 
    // (а не к виджетам, например)
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // Изменяем сортировку только в пределах страницы определенной категории
        if ( is_category( $category_id ) ) {

            // Сортировать по полю "Дата"
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );

            // Сортировать по возрастанию
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }
    }
}
```

Это примерный код (без тестирования). Его можно поместить в `functions.php` или прямо в тело шаблона вашей категории, лучше где-нибудь в начале файла, до get_header(). Не забудьте **заменить** `$category_id` на ID (или ярлык) нужной вам категории.

- Подробнее о хуке `pre_get_posts` — [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_get_posts).
- Подробнее о функции `is_category()` [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_category).
- Подробнее о параметрах выборки (order, orderby и прочем) [в документации](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

**Инфа для понимания сути, кратко:**

Хуки — это точки «перехвата», которые заранее предусмотрены разработчиками. Они позволяют «задним числом» изменять поведение функций и значения переменных в тех частях кода, которые подключаются раньше вашего.

Полный список хуков WordPress / СlassicPress есть в документации и [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/hooks/hooks-db), например. В вашем случае подходит хук `pre_get_posts` (дословно «перед выборкой постов»), который и предназначен для изменения параметров выборки.

В WordPress/СlassicPress есть два типа хуков. Один для обработки «событий», другой для для переопределения переменных. Первые подключаются функцией `add_action()`, вторые — функцией `add_filter()`. В данном случае мы внедряемся в событие `pre_get_posts`, поэтому используем add_action(). Когда событие срабатывает, хук вызывает нашу функцию сортировки.

Comment: Супер, спасибо за развернутый ответ с пояснениями, все работает!